# SAS proc sql error. The following columns were not found in the contributing tables:

Tags: mysql, sql, sas, sas-macro

I am running the below proc sql code in SAS. I get the error as 'The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: I really dont understand where is the mistake.

```
proc sql;
 create table sum_Med
  as
  select ID, count(prop_ID) as count,
  (case 
    when (count >= 5) then 1 else 0 end) as poli
  from dist_Id
 group by ID;
quit;
```

Error below:

> Error The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, SQL does not allow you to refer to column aliases in the same `SELECT` where they are defined.  That is why you are getting an error.

However, `proc sql` has a convenient workaround -- the `calculated` keyword.  So you can write this as:

```
create table sum_Med as
  select ID, count(prop_ID) as count,
         (case when calculated count >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) as poli
  from dist_Id
  group by ID;
```

Of course, you can just repeat the expression as well:

```
create table sum_Med as
  select ID, count(prop_ID) as count,
         (case when count(prop_ID) >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) as poli
  from dist_Id
  group by ID;
```

This is the traditional method for solving the problem -- and is probably needed if you are using native SQL in a connection to another database.

Comment: The first code works fine for me, Thanks. But I also tried the 2nd one it gives the same error  'The following columns were not found in the contributing tables'